# Resharper - "Widen Scope" functionality

Tags: c#, resharper

How do I widen the cope of a variable using ReSharper?

from:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public void DoSomething() 
   { 
      string widenMe = null; // i want to widen this 
   } 
 }
```

to:

```
public class MyClass 
{
   string widenMe = null; 

   public void DoSomething() 
   {  
   } 
}
```

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on your variable name (widenMe) and Ctrl+R, Ctrl+F to make it a field.

Comment: Just to note, this is based on the VS Keyboard map.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce Field (ctrl + alt + D)

Comment: +1, but that only works if you're using the 2.x/IDEA keyboard scheme ;)